# Почему OpenGL поддерживается гораздо большим спектром железа, чем Vulkan?

Tags: opengl, vulkan

Находя советы и ответы по данному вопросу от новичков, коим и являюсь я - что же начинать изучать OpenGL или Vulkan, в большинстве случаев общий ответ бывает такой, что:

> OpenGL портирован и работает сейчас даже грубо говоря на чайнике, а
> Vulkan это новая спецификация и много, чем еще не поддерживается.

И вроде все так и есть, но у меня вопрос, а почему так? Просто потому что Vulkan новый и разработчики "чайников" еще не написали драйвера под Vulkan?

Ведь теоретически для разработчиков вроде бы чуть ли не на условный порядок проще написать драйвер для Vulkan, чем для OpenGL. Или это не так?

Или может быть, что спецификация Vulkan не подходит для старых, устаревших "чайников" и видеокарт и поэтому Vulkan там никогда не сможет работать?

Comment: Просто потому,  что opengl старше. Возможно, через 50 лет vulkan будет чем то базовым, что любой мелофон будет поддерживать, а какой нибудь Гефест будет модным и молодежным. (В этом ответе много пасхалок)

Comment: *"что же начинать изучать OpenGL или Vulkan"* В последнем код рисования единственного треугольника занимает 1к+ строк кода, как я слышал. (¬‿¬) Я бы начинал с первого.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, насколько  я понимаю большая часть кода из этой 1k - занимает инициализация, которая делается один раз.

Comment: да, один раз. вот только писать нужно ее на каждое приложение. На каждое приложение нужно дублировать этот код. Почему его нельзя занести в отдельную функцию, типа "vulcan_easy_init()" (как это сделано в curl) - не знаю. видимо нельзя

Comment: @KoVadim, потому что там разные настройки инициализации используются. Там нет фиксированной инициализации, как в Curl. Насколько я понял.

Comment: Тут все зависит от того, зачем вам графика. Если забацать игру на коленке - то проще opengl.

Comment: @Optimus1 - не верю, что вот просто нельзя создать пару готовых функций для инициализаций. А для особых случаев - вот там можно и ручками. Думаю, что просто сама технология очень молодая:)

Comment: @KoVadim, посмотрите грубо, но для примера в WInApi, как инициализируется окно, там тоже куча параметров и относительно не мало кода. А технология явно не молодая.

Comment: Ну дефли сделали же и спрятали это все

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vulkan одновременно и  на порядок  сложнее в реализации и потенциально на порядок  требовательнее к возможностям железа. Причем он разросся не только в глубь (например предлагает вычислительные шейдеры и средства для трассировки лучей), но и в ширину (например туда запихнули и создание swap chains и работу с форматом SPIR‐V). А всякие упрощения, существовавшие в OpengGL со старых времен, прежде всего fixed-function pipeline, в нем отсутствуют. В то время как например в редакции ES OpenGL предназначен для самых простых устройств с минимумом возможностей.

Comment: Вроде [сообщалось](https://www.khronos.org/assets/uploads/developers/library/overview/vulkan-overview.pdf), что Vulkan теоретически может работать на устройствах, умеющих в OpenGL ES 3.1 (главное чтобы производитель сделал новый драйвер), так что подозреваю, что фраза «предназначен для самых простых устройств» уже не очень актуальна для последних версий OpenGL ES

Comment: @andreymal Вполне может быть, ведь Vulkan появился примерно в то же время. Однако OpenGL ES 3.1 также не особо подходит для старых, устаревших "чайников". Тот же гугл до сих пор рекомендует 2.0

Comment: fixed-function pipeline в самом OpenGL - это дичайший legacy и deprecated, его в самом OpenGl никто уже не использует.

Comment: Если брать первую версию Vulkan - разве он на ПОРЯДОК требовательнее к возможностям железа, чем OpenGl. Из чего такое заявление следует ?

Comment: @Optimus1 Первая версия вполне сравнима с последними версиями OpenGL. Например представленный в прошлом году гугл [Android Baseline profile](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/graphics/android-baseline-profile) как раз базируется еще на первом Vulkan и примерно ориентируется на уровень OpenGL ES 3.1. То, что этот профиль только вышел, хорошо показывает требовательность Vulkan и его применимость в области мобильных устройств. Наверное году к 30 доберется до мейнстрима.

Comment: @Optimus1 Я тут еще заглянул на https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards и, к моему удивлению, там показывается что поддержка Vulkan есть уже у 75% процентов устройств. А вроде еще пару лет назад фигурировала цифра порядка 15%. Там правда не ясно, какая выборка устройств берется, однако среди новых аппаратов поддержка Vulkan, хотя бы номинальная, явно уже приобретает массовый характер.